# Failed audit because of its answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, disputed-review-audits, triage

I have just [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7957167) (and apparently I failed one too many - no triage for me for 2 days!). Apparently, the user is spamming/promoting in his **answer**.

[image: Failed audit]

I saw the comment of Bill, which made me want to put "Unsalvageable", but it was apparently in the answer that the spam was - not in the question!

As I couldn't see the answer, I thought the question itself needed improvement - not many informations, no research, etc. But should have I flagged as spam, even if the said-spam is in the answer? Or is the audit broken?

Comment: I don't suppose you have a screenshot? The link is 10k only.

Comment: Oh, sorry! A second please @NathanTuggy

Comment: The comment says *It's fine to answer your own question, but (...)* implying that this was a self-answered question that the OP posted for the sole purpose of adding an answer containing spam.

Comment: Hence my question : should have I flagged even if the spam is not in the question? I mean, the question alone is okay.

Comment: Should be improved is to gentle, that question should be closed, at least. There is no way any user in the helper queue can edit that question into shape.

Comment: **Triage review PSA**: You're not using "needs improvement" correctly! Clicking "needs improvement" in Triage sends the question to the "Help and Improvement" queue to be improved _by the community, not by OP_. If you're using it on questions because the question doesn't contain enough information or OP didn't do research, _this is not something that the community can fix_ and thus all you're doing is filling the HIQ with crap. Please instead review questions that need improvement _by OP_ as "unsalvageable -> unclear" (or another close reason if one is more appropriate).

Comment: Oh; well, thank you! That _needs improvement_ field is not too clear..

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah that's really unclear. I just put needs to be improved when it's not giving enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added checks to ensure that only posts which were actually deleted by the system in response to spam flags are used for this purpose - this should avoid situations where posts deleted for other reasons (for instance, because they were created to host spam in *answers*, as was the case here) are used.

See: [NSFW triage review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362493/nsfw-triage-review-audit/377864#377864)

Answer (score 4):

We have multiple questions regarding the same subject. A similar question is : [Can someone please explain why this question was flagged as spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293710/can-someone-please-explain-why-this-question-was-flagged-as-spam).

> But should have I flagged as spam

You should have clicked on **Unsalvageable**.

There are 4 options available in the **Triage** review:

[image]

For the audit question, it **doesn't** come under following categories:

- Looks OK
- Should Be Improved

Because, it doesn't look OK for sure and should be closed. It can't be improved by the *community* as it could only be improved by OP, so you shouldn't click *Should Be Improved*.

So, you are left with two options:

- Unsalvageable
- Skip

If you were not sure about it, you should have skipped it rather than simply clicking Looks OK.

It is not salvageable because as I already said, community won't be able to improve such a poor post which lacks a lot of information. Only OP could add more information. Community cannot research on it and add the expected content.

When you click on Unsalvageable, you would see this popup:

[image]

Next, you need to select the reason you think the question should be closed:

[image]

In short, the post was not OK, so your review was incorrect. And, of course, you failed the audit.

Comment: I never said that the post was OK. However, the question is rather clear - it only needed efforts in formatting!

Comment: There is another similar questions, which asks why is it flagged as spam. So, I have covered all the points. Since the other question is flagged as duplicate of this question.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. However, I still think that the question alone was not unsalvageable - don't you think that it was clear enough for the community to fix?

Comment: @Docteur while my first impression was also  unsalvagable is appropriate, on a second thought, the question is indeed almost clear: Give me the tables and datasets with most data: Here is the only issue: What consitutes most data, but I guess an answer in number of table entries would be enough and would have been acceptable.

Comment: @Docteur You cannot expect the community to research and add the required content. The community will give it's hand to improve the posted content as far as possible.

Comment: @martin And what about the research effort?

Comment: If it was only for the research effort, you'd close almost all regex questions. Use a downvote for this reason, not a close vote.

Comment: Firstly, there is no point comparing two completely different questions. Secondly, `regex` questions mostly which I answered, the question includes which regex function the user wants, or shows what he has tried and not getting desired output.

Comment: @martin By the way, OP reviewed as "Should be improved", and thus failed in audit. What could be the improvement you think?