# Can someone please explain why this question was flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage, spam

I was triaging some new questions and flagged one as OK which I was then told was bait, previously flagged as spam, and I had failed by marking it OK. I cannot for the life of me see why the question should be considered spam. A comment to the question - not shown until after I had triaged the question - made some mention of an answer, which I did not see and cannot access, but as far as I can see the question is reasonable, and within the Stack Overflow domain. The *answer* might have been spam, but I was asked to triage the question, not the answer.
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: This same audit was discussed here a few days ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293466/failed-audit-because-of-its-answer

Comment: So I'm not the only one caught :-)

Comment: Heheh, nope. :-) The lesson that I've learned and that I recommend to you : if there are some comments discussing OP's actions that are not in the question, check anyway. The audit tool is not perfect - us neither - and sometimes this happens.

Comment: I could understand if you had clicked Should Be Improved and you had failed the audit, but there is nothing Ok about that question.

Comment: As far as I recall I was not shown the comment during the triage. And I'm not sure what you're suggesting I should have checked - the spam answer is not available.

Comment: That's the thing : seeing that the question was gone should have compelled both of us to put a flag. It's cheating, though, and it's the reason I failed - not doing that :-P

Comment: Kind of puts one off attempting any triage if there are trick questions.

Comment: Sure, it's not spam, but it's not "OK" either. It's very low quality.

Comment: @animuson The lack of apparent research would have warranted a comment, but that doesn't make the question unsalvageable. "Should be improved is", according the the earlier meta discussion, not the right classification because that suggests the community should review and improve the question.  So that only leaves OK and Skip.

Comment: So, because those options don't make sense, youcd rather just click the Ok button and let a truly terrible question just sit on the site? If you don't think the community could improve it, then you should have clicked Unsalvageable. Ok is as far from the correct thing as you could get.

Comment: I don't think I'd classify the question as "truly terrible". Ignoring the post-hoc knowledge of attempted spamming, the question  simply needed expansion. I've seen plenty of questions on the site that have been poor quality but in response to comments have been improved by the OPs - that's a learning experience.

Comment: _"the question simply needed expansion"_ So, it's __not__ "OK".

Comment: It is a good triage question to teach people the unsalvagable button.

Comment: @martin I can understand animuson his explanation but this question is definitely not unsalvagable.

Comment: @Loko It is by the definition of the triage queue: Hit unsalvagable if the author is the only one able to improve the question. Hit needs improvement if the community can improve it.

Comment: @Loko But you are right, it's borderline, it may be answered as it is, but what is most data? Rows, columns, non null entries?

Comment: @martin The button shouldn't be called "Unsalvagable" in my opinion.

Comment: @Loko, yes, it sounds harder than what most people would say.

Comment: There are at least two issues that have become intertwined here. One is what criteria should be used to choose the triage response - checking the explanation on the triage page - "Should Be Improved for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable" - so my answer of OK to this was wrong.

Comment: The other issue is whether this is a valid question for triage auditing - I gave a wrong answer, but Docteur answered "Should be improved" which is clearly the right answer (since with additional information from the OP it could have been salvaged) but he also failed the audit. So in my view this question should be removed from the audit pool as the accepted answer relies upon information not available to the person performing triage.

Comment: @martin The triage queue says about Unsalvageable : "for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site". "Should be improved" is defined as "for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable". Note "by the author or others".

Comment: @Clyde, yes that is different from what has been said here on meta and should be addressed.